# Unable to Search For Numbers in Outlook 2010 and 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have ran into an issue that has followed me from Outlook 2010 to the newest version of Office365 Outlook 2016.

A user is required to search for numerical data for order numbers and such.
Searching for words in the search bar works fine. However, searching for numbers just does not work. Even though I can see a mail in the inbox with the string of numbers I searched for, it states that no results were found!
We have rebuilt the search cache I also found a technet article which states the advanced search function would be a workaround for this.. it is not as this does not work either.

Has anyone ran into a fix for this issue?

Comment: It just works fine for me in Outlook 2013. Are your codes pure numbers or do they contain other characters too. Have you tried putting them in quotes (e.g. `"123-456"`)?

Comment: Quotes does not work either and they do contain an individual character such as P

Comment: do you have the same issue with all numbers occurring in mails, or just those codes? Can you post some screenshots (with hiding confidential information of course)?

Comment: Its a user on my network who is Dutch and the language is in Dutch. I don't think it will be possible to get pictures without replicating this issue myself... I will try and do so and post it.

Comment: it's always good to replicate issues on multiple computers first ...

Comment: Yeah I would but Ive never seen it happen anywhere else on our network so I assumed it was local to her machine.